# I lack referential integrity, how to insert a number after a score if the value does not have enough digits?

Tags: pandas, if-statement

```
import pandas as pd

data_1 = [['1010-0123',5500, '01/02/21'], ['1010-223',8500, '11/02/20']]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns = ['ID', 'Sold', 'Date'])

data_2 = [['1010-0123',3500], ['1010-0223',5500]]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns = ['ID', 'Price'])

df_3 = df_1.ID.str.split("-",expand = True)
df_3.columns = ['STATUS_ID{}'.format(x+1) for x in df_3.columns]

df_1 = ubr.join(df_3)
```

At this point I will need to add these two columns but I must first make sure the second part contains 4 digits, if it contains 3 I need to add a 0 before all digits and then add it with the other column.  XXXX-XXXX

```
df_merge = pd.merge(data_2, data_1, on ='ID', how='left')
```

The result is only one row instead of the two.

How can I check its digits and if it aint 9 then insert number '0' after the '-'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering missing digits can only appear in the second id part, you can use the following code to fill them with 0 before merging.

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x) == 9 else x[:5] + '0'*(9-len(x)) + x[5:])
```